# look for a value in a table by comparing it with another value

Tags: excel, vba, row, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a table contains two columns A and B and 257 rows.
the column A contain values in ascending order.
I have a random value for example 29974
i want to find the first value that is greater than 29974 in the column A (going from 1 to 257 ) and take the value of column B of the same row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INDEX MATCH:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(29974,A:A)+1)
```

vba:

```
ans = ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Match(29974,ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))+1,2).Value
```

Comment: the table contains random values in ascending order , in this example the result should be 29980 because it is the first value greater then 29974 and give the value in column B in the same row

Comment: This should work with that.  did it not work?